# Mark mount as network mount (or disable nautilus thumbnails on certain mounts)

Tags: networking, mount, nautilus, fstab

By default nautilus only generates thumbnails for local mounts, so it skips network drives.

Unfortunately, certain fuse and unionfs mounts are not recognised as being network drives, so it thinks it can just read those files as if they're local, but that trashes my internet link.

Is there a way to indicate to nautilus, or the entire system even, that a certain mount is really a network drive?